setting up a popup for the woocommerce checkout
I have a WP woocommerce site that I am working on. I would like a popup on a child of the checkout page but not the actual checkout page. In my popup I currently have the following display conditions:

If I remove the bottom display condition so that I only have the child of checkout nothing displays. If I leave it as is, the popup will display on both the checkout page and its child page as expected. I would expect that it should work with only the child, but it does not.
I have also tried creating a custom page and setting up the "order received" url within woocommerce settings:

this still gives me an absolute path of checkout/test-order when I would prefer just /test-order.
Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.
